# Does columnar storage insert will shift the memory blocks?

Tags: amazon-redshift, hana, columnstore

In columnar storage column data will be stored contagiously and if there is any insert does the shifting of block happens? I believe it is more expensive to shift the block. How is this internally managed ?

Comment: is it Redshift of Hana? 2 dif systems

Comment: I need to understand how it will be managed irrespective of which DB it is.

Answer (score 0):

## Not immediately

This is indeed a very costly operation, so it is mostly delayed, and only performed occasionally.

Changes of each main table (inserts, modifies, updates) are colleced into a *delta table*, and they are [merged into the main table](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.02/en-US/bd9ac728bb57101482b2ebfe243dcd7a.html) when some preset conditions are met.<sup>1</sup>

---

1) If the delta table has more lines than X1, becomes bigger than X2 percent of the main table, X3 time passed since the last merge, etc. All X variables are changeable.

Comment: For redshift, my understanding is that items get appended on to the end of the columns (out of order) and then when you vacuum (and it's unsorted enough to be worth the effort) it will re-sort the columns. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html